# Save program logs into a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

**I want to save the program log (shown in screen) into a text file but I'm having difficulties in integrating the def() part.**

**So far, my data_log is(saved in file):**

Date and Time: 2021-12-21 16:05:50.927868

Input: [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]

Recursion: [[3, 5, 7, 9], [2, 2, 2], [0, 0], [0]]

With this regard, I want to save the program logs stated at the end of this query rather than my data_log program. I am a high school student.

[image: Similar concept was shown in this picture:]

```
user = input("Name:")

def shrink(numbers, return_list=[]):
    n1 = [(x, numbers[i + 1]) for i, x in enumerate(numbers) if i < len(numbers) - 1]
    n2 = [x[1] - x[0] for x in n1]

    return_list.append(n2)

    if (len(n2) > 1):
        return shrink(n2, return_list)
    else:
        return return_list

input_user = input("Enter data:")
b = input_user.split()
for num in range(len(b)):
    b[num] = int(b[num])
c = shrink(b)
print(c)

def sequence_identifier():
    from fractions import Fraction


    #3 Quadratic Sequence
    if len(c[0:len(c)]) >= 2:
        if c[1][:-1] == c[1][1:] and sum(c[1]) != 0 and len(c[1]) > 1:
            print('Sequence type: quadratic sequence')
            x = Fraction((c[1][0])/2)
            y = Fraction(c[0][0]-(x*3))
            z = Fraction(1 - (x + y))
            print('The general formula is: an^2 + bn + c')
            print('a:',str(x))
            print('b:',str(y))
            print('c:',str(z))
            print('Would you like to find an nth term?[Press 1]')
            Yes3 = int(input())
            if Yes3 == 1:
                while True:
                    nth3_1 = int(input('What is the nth term:'))
                    nthterm3_1 = ((x)*(nth3_1**2) + (y*nth3_1) + z)
                    print('The nth term is', nthterm3_1)
                    print('Would you like to try again?')
                    confirmloop3_1 = int(input('Press 1 to continue:'))
                    if confirmloop3_1 == 1: continue
                    else: break

sequence_identifier()

# I want to modify this:
with open(user, 'a+') as data_log:
    from datetime import datetime
    data_log.write(str('_'*100))
    data_log.write('\n')
    data_log.write('Date and Time: '+ str(datetime.now()))
    data_log.write('\n')
    data_log.write('Input: '+ str(b))
    data_log.write('\n')
    data_log.write('Recursion: '+ str(c))
    data_log.write('\n')
    data_log.close()
```

**The screen log of this program is:**
*(Italics are input)*

Name:*Ralph*

Enter data:*1 4 9 16 25*

[[3, 5, 7, 9], [2, 2, 2], [0, 0], [0]]

Sequence type: quadratic sequence

The general formula is: an^2 + bn + c

a: 1

b: 0

c: 0

Would you like to find an nth term?[Press 1]

*1*

What is the nth term:*10*

The nth term is 100

Would you like to try again?

Press 1 to continue:*2*

Comment: Hey I can try and help but what exactly do you want to modify, if you want to save all of the input you can continue to write the values to data_log, like you did for b.

Comment: Thank You. I just want to save all the contents in the terminal: Like a copy-paste of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use logging package and give some basicConfig to save logs in required format

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='app.log', filemode='w', format='%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
logging.warning('This will get logged to a file')
```

You can user logging.error, logging.info, logging.debug based on the log you are writing.
All these logs will be stored in the file mentioned in the filename.